# AngularJS : Angular UI-router: How to inject state params into an abstract state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

As you can see in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vZzh33HNFwRpHQFAY4N?p=preview) I've added 3 more states to an Ionic side-menu starter template. Clicking on the menu item `calendar`, the abstract state, `app.calendar`, is called by his children state `app.calendar.a`, the abstract state has a `resolve:` configuration object that fetch data based on a default parameter, if nothing is provided,(I tried to add `params:{year:{value:'2015'}}` but I get `Error: Invalid params in state 'app.calendar'`). So in this case I'm unable to give a default value useful for the resolve function. Moreover when you click on the `goto state B` button, you reach the new state only after the second transition.

Comment: i would first start by turning off view caching because when I look at the console i dont see it getting updated as often as I believe it should be .

Comment: @AaronSaunders Unfortunately I forked an old Ionic version it was the 1.0.0-beta.1. With the latest release I was able to add the default parameter to the abstract state and with the cached option activated everything is working as expected thx.